# Different thread owns it in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

This is a `UserControl` that I am using.

this.CardHolderName.Content is a `label` that is in the UI of the user control.

```
public partial class PersonCredential : UserControl
        {
            public PersonCredential()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action) (() => {
                        SCLib type = new SCLib();
                        type.StartMonitoring();

                        type.CardArrived += (string ATR) => { this.CardHolderName.Content = ATR; };
                    };
               }));
```

I am still getting the error , "***The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it***" even though I am using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

Is there something wrong in the way the `Dispatcher` is used ?
                }

EDIT:
I am instantiating that user control inside a content control and the code-behind is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       PersonCredential personCredential {get;set;}

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            var personCredential = new CoffeeShop.PersonCredential();
            //create an instance of user control.
            this.personCredentials.Content = personCredential;
            // assign it to the content control inside the wpf main window
            .. // blah blah
        }
```

EDIT 1:

Code for start-Monitoring:

```
public async void StartMonitoring()
        {

            // Wait for user to press a key

            try
            {
                this.establishContext();

                await Task.Run(new Action(WaitForReaderArrival));
                ////WaitForReaderArrival();

                if (IsReaderArrived())
```

Comment: Is constructor called from background thread? That itself is an issue. You should create all UI things (including UserControl) on UI thread.

Comment: @RohitVats: Actually, this is a `user-control` and I use instantiate this in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` class!

Comment: Yeah that's fine. But my question why are using `Dispatcher` at all here? If constructor is called on UI thread, you don't need to dispatch back to UI thread.

Comment: @RohitVats: I removed the `Dispatcher` statement and used the normal code. Still throws the same error.

Comment: Please post the code from where you are instantiating this userControl.

Comment: Also the result of `CheckAccess()` might be interesting.

Comment: @RohitVats: I have updated.

Comment: @RohitVats: Rohit, could you kindly let me know why a `dispatcher inside a thread or a task works fine` ?

Comment: @OP could you post the code for `SCLib`? What do `StartMonitoring` and `CardArrived` look like? You want to monitor on another thread, correct?

Comment: @Alden: `StartMonitoring` waits in an infinite loop for any `smartcard reader` to arrive. When one comes in, a `CardArrived` event is raised.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed I just updated my answer to include an explanation, which @DanPuzey beat me to in the comments. The event is being raised from another thread - the thread you are starting in `StartMonitoring`

Comment: @Alden: thank you. Learned a lot today:)

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed, how much time does each `IsReaderArrived()` take? Are you sure you need a separate thread for `StartMonitoring` task, and cannot loop asynchronously on the UI thread with something lie `await Task.Delay(500)`?

Comment: @Noseratio: I want a `reusable` and `separate library` for keeping the implementation clean. If it had been `integrated in to the UI`, I cannot re-use it for another project. Thats why...

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed, `Task.Delay(500)` is in no way specific to a UI thread. More, if you use it like `await Task.Delay(500).ConfigureAwait(false)`, the code after `await` will run a pool thread.

Comment: @Noseratio: Thanks Noseratio. But, if i develop this plugin and integrate in to the `UI`, I might have problems in `re-using` it in another projects ? Or i still don't understand things ? Sorry, kindly point me in right direction if I am not already.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed, I explained that in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21694265/1768303).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** from @DanPuzey's comments. `StartMonitoring` already monitors on another thread. The key is that the `CardArrived` event is not being raised from the UI thread:

```
public PersonCredential()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SCLib type = new SCLib();
    type.StartMonitoring();

    type.CardArrived += (string ATR) => { 
        // when card arrives, dispatch back to UI thread
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            this.CardHolderName.Content = ATR; 
        }));
    };
}
```

And if you are using .NET 4 or higher, use [`Task.Factory.StartNew()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `new Thread()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And it would be really helpful if you could kindly point me `why the dispatcher without a new thread does not work` but the same task under a `thread` runs fine ?

Comment: I don't think the `new Thread( ...).Start()` is needed - the important part of this solution is the `Dispatcher.Invoke` in the event handler. An event handler *won't* typically be called from the dispatcher thread, and that's where the error is likely coming from.

Comment: @DanPuzey yes exactly, but `StartMonitoring` waits in an infinitely loop, see the comments on the question

Comment: @DanPuzey : Yup , you are right. Just removed the `new Thread(...).Start()` and everything works the same :)

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed I thought you said `StartMonitoring` waits in an infinite loop? Does it start it's own thread?

Comment: If `StartMonitoring()` waits in an infinite loop then the event handler would never be set (the code would block in an infinite loop before reaching `type.CardArrived += ...`) - so I don't think your statement is quite correct.

Comment: @DanPuzey yes I supposed you are correct... start monitoring must spin up a thread itself

Comment: @Alden: I think yes because I use `Task.Run`

Comment: @Alden, @DanPuzey : Now I understand from the statement, `The key is that the CardArrived event is not being raised from the UI thread:`

Answer (score 1):

If the `IsReaderArrived` check is an instant non-blocking call (i.e., it takes less than ~50ms to complete), I'd suggest to start the polling loop on the caller's thread, using `Task.Delay(interval)`:

```
public async Task StartMonitoring(int interval, CancellationToken token)
{
    this.establishContext();

    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        if (IsReaderArrived())
        {
            // make sure to reset the flag inside IsReaderArrived
            // so the event won't be fired upon the next iteration 

            if (this.CardArrived != null)
                this.CardArrived(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        await Task.Delay(interval);
    }
}
```

This is an asynchronous loop. If `StartMonitoring` is called from a UI thread, the `CardArrived` event will be fired on the same UI thread and the client of your code won't have to worry about `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. If you need an explanation of how this is happening, read ["It's All About the SynchronizationContext."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks a lot... `Dispatcher` now seems not necessary!